# How can I show next date and time from list of date time using PHP?

Tags: php

I have following date format value in mysql database :

```
1464436800 ( In php, date will be 2016-05-28 8:00 AM )
1464440400 ( In php, date will be 2016-05-28 9:00 AM )
1464444000 ( In php, date will be 2016-05-28 10:00 AM )
1464447600 ( In php, date will be 2016-05-28 11:00 AM )
1464552000 ( In php, date will be 2016-05-29 4:00 Am )
```

Now I want to show Next date and time using php from those list of database value.

For e.g :  If the current date and time is **2016-05-25 8:00 AM** then I want to select/show next date time like this one **2016-05-28 9:00 AM**

The next date and time could be after 1 hour or 2 hour or 5 hours or after 1 day or 2 days etc..

But the text date and time is showing in the list of datetime value in my database like I shown it.

How can I do this with php ?

**Update :**

```
<?php
$get_menu = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT products.p_title, products.p_price, product_images.p_list_image, chef_profile.live_at, chef_profile.fname, chef_profile.lname, chef_profile.is_verified_chef, users.user_avator, chef_review.r_star, product_date_time.date, product_date_time.time FROM products LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.p_id = product_images.p_id LEFT JOIN chef_profile ON products.u_id = chef_profile.u_id LEFT JOIN users ON products.u_id = users.u_id LEFT JOIN chef_review ON products.p_id =  chef_review.p_id LEFT JOIN product_date_time ON product_date_time.p_id = products.p_id GROUP BY products.p_id");

$num_menu =  mysqli_num_rows($get_menu);
while( $get_result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_menu) ) {

$menu_title = htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($get_result['p_title']));
$menu_price = htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_price']);        
$menu_image = htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_list_image']) ? htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_list_image']) : "no-menu-preview.png";
$live_at =  htmlspecialchars($get_result['live_at']);
$fname = htmlspecialchars($get_result['fname']);
$lname = htmlspecialchars($get_result['lname']);
$date = htmlspecialchars($get_result['date']);        

if(!empty($date)) {
    $date_time = 'Next Date : ';
    $date_time .= date('D, F jS', $date);
    $date_time .= ' at ';
    $date_time .= date('G:00 A', $date);
} else {
    $date_time = 'No event time found';
}

$user_avator =  htmlspecialchars($get_result['user_avator']) ? htmlspecialchars($get_result['user_avator']) : "empty-photo.jpg";

$is_verified =  (int) $get_result['is_verified_chef'];
if($is_verified == 1) {
    $is_verified = '<small><i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>&nbsp;Verified Chef</small>';
} elseif($is_verified == 0) {
    $is_verified = '<small>Not Verified</small>';
}
$r_star =  (int) $get_result['r_star'];

?>


<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">               
     <div class="items">
        <div class="img-effect">

            <a href="menu-details?<?php ?>"><img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR."menu_images/$menu_image" ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list">                
            <div class="col-md-9 no-p-m product-title">
                <h4><a href="product-list"><?php echo $menu_title; ?></a></h4>                        
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 price">
                <p class="text-right">$ <?php echo $menu_price; ?></p>        
            </div>
            <hr class="items-hr">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR."users_avator/$user_avator" ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive img-circle" width="100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <p><strong>Chef <?php echo $fname . ' ' . $lname; ?></strong></p>                        
                    <em><?php echo $live_at; ?></em>                               
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 review">
                        <?php echo $is_verified; ?><br/>                                
                        <?php
                        if($r_star == 0 ) {
                              echo 'No Review';
                        } else {
                            for($x = 1; $x <= $r_star; $x++) {
                                 echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";                                        
                            }
                            echo " ($r_star Review)";
                        }
                       ?>
                    </div>                     
                </div>                    
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="next-date">
            <p><?php echo $date_time; ?></p>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Something like this`$date = strtotime("+3 day", strtotime("2016-05-28 8:00 AM")); echo date("Y-m-d", $date)`

Comment: I updated my question. Please check it

Comment: Yes my script do what you want

Comment: see online example: [https://3v4l.org/XsgIJ](https://3v4l.org/XsgIJ)

Comment: Make two query, one for only dates and one for everything. make array from from first query and display them in second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use from following structure:

```
$newdate =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

you can replace 30 number with each days you need

Comment: not each day. did you check my list of datetime value ? The next date could after 1 hour or 3 hour or 7 hours or after 1 day or after 2 day 2 hour  etc..

Comment: Yes, i read. check this one: $newdate =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 hour", strtotime("2016-05-28 8:00")));
you can +1 hour or day and ....

Comment: Also there are manual of this section: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Also you can define output format which each structure which you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: But I don't know that it will be +1 or +2 or day.

Comment: You can define variable for this issue, for example define $typeOfSum = 'day', $amountOf Sum = '1'; and use from this variables in the  $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 hour", strtotime("2016-05-28 8:00")));

Answer (score 1):

During runtime of this while loop, you have no clue what all event times are.  Therefore you can't select one. They are flowing in (as i understand it).
You have to have all data first, to select the next one.

Therefore you have 3 Options:

## 1. Reverse the output

By Reversing the Output (considering it is sorted by datetime), you can keep a variable `$nextEvent`. I would say this is the prefered method, if you can sort your Data later on in the Browser, or sorting by server is irrelevant.

```
<?php
$get_menu = mysqli_query($conn, "[...] ORDER BY <date> DESC");

$num_menu =  mysqli_num_rows($get_menu);
$nextEvent = '';
while( $get_result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_menu) ) {

    [...]
    $date = htmlspecialchars($get_result['date']);        

    if(!empty($nextEvent)) {
        echo 'Next Event at: '.$nextEvent;
    }
    $nextEvent = $date;
    [...]
}
```

## 2. You run all events twice

Running all twice means, that you have a while loop and save the data in arrays and run through this array later on during output.
Now you have all data and my method still applies applies.

Considering you have an array with your values

```
<?php
$a = array(
    1464436800,
    1464440400,
    1464444000,
    1464447600,
    1464552000
);
```

You can do an `array_search` on `array_values` and you get the position of the the element you are looking. If you then +1 this (considering you are not at the last one), you will end up with the next element.

```
sort($a); // Just to be on the safe side, it is in the right order
var $index = array_search('1464444000',array_values($a));
if($index !== count($a)) {
    // next Element $a[$index+1];
} else {
    echo 'you are already at the last one'
}
```

## 3. You make a SQL Query every time in the loop

*(Not Recommended)*

You can make an SQL Query to select the next event every time a event is processed. **BUT** it will be a huge slowdown, because a lot of SQL Querys have to be run.

Comment: You see my while loop in my question. I don't know the next date time and All date and time will be shown in while loop and next date and time could be any time.

Comment: If you can reverse the output you can save the previous time (If the Select is sorted by Datetime). But other than that i'm afraid you have to write out the data first and then loop through it. You can't predict the next one, if it is "random"

Comment: Let me explain it again : User can add multiple date and time for their event. I inserted all the selected date and time to database using `strtotime`. So I want to show next event date time from our current time

Comment: edited the answer to support multiple methods, explanation of each method. Hope one fits you.

Comment: I am reading it. but I can see my query is showing first matching date and time from the db. If there is a 4 date and time then now it's showing me first date and time. So If I change my query e.g : product_date_time.date > time(),. will it be work ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but i think it should, coz `order by` runs after a join. So you should add to your query `ORDER BY date DESC` and the output should be sorted by datetime reverse, and you can use method 1. (I am not quite sure where this `date`comes from.)

Answer (score 0):

To select next row first you need to convert  time to timestamp using php

```
echo $newdate = strtotime("2016-05-28 8:00");// get timestamp
```

Then use query to get new time from database

```
SELECT next_date FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE next_date > $newdate ORDER BY next_date LIMIT 1;
```

You can create yo array inside while loop as

```
$array[] = htmlspecialchars($get_result['date']);
```

To get new value form array use

```
$array = array(
    '0'=>1464436800,
    '1'=>1464440400,
    '2'=>1464444000,
    '3'=>1464447600,
    '4'=>1464552000
);

echo current(array_slice($array, array_search(0, array_keys($array)) + 1, 1));// pass your array key into array_search
```

Check [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DQG3p)

Comment: OP want it in PHP. _How can I do this with php_.

Comment: @Saty I am showing all date and time in php while loop. In this while loop I want to show next date and time from current date and time.

Comment: You can make an array of the `date_time` and for each date display just increase the index of that array.

Comment: I don't understand @Frayne Konok.

Comment: See the last answer posted by @nv1t.

Comment: @Saty according to your given and my condition the DEMO should be this : 1464436800 because that time is next first time.

Comment: You pass key into search array if key is 0 it echo 1464440400. In my demo i pass key 2 it echo key 3 value

Comment: @Saty  in my join query can I used :  product_date_time.date > time(), ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

add field name to your database to purpose as counter.
for example:

```
+----------+----+
|dateTime  |cntr|
+----------+----+
|1464440400| 1  |
|1464444000| 2  |
|1464447600| 3  |
|1464552000| 4  |
+----------+----+
```

PHP/MYSQL:

```
$q1 = SELECT cntr FROM tableName WHERE dateTime = 'yourDate';

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){

    $cntr = $result['cntr']+1;//add 1 to get the next count in table

    $q2 = SELECT dateTime FROM tableName WHERE cntr = '$cntr';

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($q2);

        echo $data['dateTime']; //result
}
```